# Grunt + rollup + babel config issue

Tags: gruntjs, babeljs, rollup

I cannot make rollup transform my ES6 code into ES5. It stays trowing a message `Warning: Error transforming main.js with 'babel' plugin: It looks like your Babel configuration specifies a module transformer. Please disable it. If you're using the "es2015" preset, consider using "es2015-rollup" instead. See https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel#configuring-babel for more information Use --force to continue.`

My `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "es2015-rollup",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["external-helpers"]
}
```

My `.gruntfile`

```
"use strict";
var babel = require('rollup-plugin-babel');

module.exports = function( grunt ) {

  grunt.initConfig({

    //...

    rollup: {
      options: {
        plugins: function () {
          return [
            babel({
              babelrc: false,
              presets: ["es2015-rollup"]
            })
          ];
        },
      },
      main: {
        'dest': 'build/js/bundle.js',
        'src' : 'src/js/main.js',
      },
    },

  //...

  });

  // Load the tasks
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-notify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-postcss');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-rollup');

  grunt.registerTask( 'default', [ 'rollup', 'watch' ] );
  //...
};
```

My `devDependencies`

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^6.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-external-helpers": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015-rollup": "^1.2.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-babel": "^6.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-notify": "^0.4.3",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt-rollup": "^0.8.0",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^2.6.1"
  }
```

As you can see, I use the `es2015-rollup` preset and not `es2015` as the warning suggests. Another thing is that if I remove the presets, my code doesn't get transpilled at all.

Answer (score 0):

`plugins` option should be an array, not a function.

Also, in `.babelrc`, you should use `es2015` instead of `es2015-rollup`, because the rollup version is just `es2015` with `external-helpers` plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you set babelrc: false, your configuration will not read **.babelrc** configuration file.

ignore your **.babelrc** file and try this in your babel plugin configuration in **Gruntfile.js**:

```
 babel({
    babelrc: false,
    presets: [["es2015",{modules:false}]],
    exclude: ['./node_modules/**/*'], //make sure to point to your folder path
    plugins: ["external-helpers"]
 })
```